# nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=203

Tags: nginx, centos

I installed nginx 1.10.2 on centos7.2 using yum. Then I used the command `systemctl start nginx.service` to start it. It shows

```
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Running `systemctl status nginx.service` shows

```
鈼[0m nginx.service - The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor       preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-04-14 17:00:12 CST; 49min ago
 Main PID: 3617 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Apr 14 17:00:12 izwz9hc2sfq1r799vqco2lz systemd[1]: Starting The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server...
Apr 14 17:00:12 izwz9hc2sfq1r799vqco2lz systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=203
Apr 14 17:00:12 izwz9hc2sfq1r799vqco2lz systemd[1]: Failed to start The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
Apr 14 17:00:12 izwz9hc2sfq1r799vqco2lz systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
Apr 14 17:00:12 izwz9hc2sfq1r799vqco2lz systemd[1]: nginx.service failed.
```

Please tell how to start nginx.

Comment: Is you configuration file well written? You check use `nginx -t` to do that.

Comment: Just look at : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204312/nginx-init-d-script

Comment: Use command nginx -t,it shows -bash: nginx: command not found

Comment: @周晨曦 Try the following: `sudo /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -t -c /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf`. If not, then find out where your nginx has been installed.

Answer (score 0):

Run nginx from command line and it will show erros on terminal. Once these errors are solved then you can start using systemctl command. Possible reasons are as follows.

/var/log/nginx/error.log
/var/log/nginx/access.log

Use touch command and mkdir command to create fodlers and files as needed.